# Do users need to change the socket type to use XDP?

Tags: xdp-bpf

If we want to bypass the kernel network stack, it looks like we'll have to use AF_XDP sockets.

Does that mean we have to modify the user-space program ?

But with so many APKs, is it difficult for so many APKs to cooperate with modification?

Personally, I feel the application scenario is very limited.

Answer (score 0):

The kernel can indeed be bypassed using the `AF_XDP` sockets. The main selling point of using XDP is that you can selectively bypass. Your XDP program can for example chose to only bypass traffic for a specific IP+TCP port, allowing the rest of the system to run like normal. So you don't need to modify all applications, just the one you would like to use kernel bypassing for.

Bypassing the network stack also means that the kernels doesn't do anything for you anymore(TCP retransmission, packet acknowledgement, reordering, defragmentation). So any application which wan't to bypass the kernel must also implement its own network stack to use it like a normal socket. If that is your usecase, you might want to look into [DPDK](https://www.dpdk.org/) which optionally uses XDP under the hood but does a lot more for you.

As for typical use cases:

- Custom protocol implementation
- Packet capture of blocks(in an DDoS protection senario, you might want to forward 1 in a 1000 packets via AF_XDP instread of blocking for inspection purposes)
- [DPDK](https://www.dpdk.org/) and [OvS](https://docs.openvswitch.org/en/latest/intro/install/afxdp/) can use it
- Any other packet processing outside of eBPF(if eBPF is to limiting, one can do packet processing in userspace with little overhead. The main limitation is that you can't TX to the local kernel from userspace, but you can modify the packet and make a DROP or re-transmit decision)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am thinking about more scenarios of XDP, such as whether TikTok on android phones can use XDP to enhance throughput. 
As far as I understand, first of all, Google or chip vendor(Qualcomm or MTK) need to support XDP programs to bypass the kernel protocol stack. In addition, TikTok needs to modify the socket type to AF_XDP to use XDP. . I don't know if my understanding is correct.

Comment: Yes, the network driver has to implement XDP support to get the promised performance(skb vs driver mode), your app should start using AF_XDP sockets and implement your own network stack. And yes, In theory, you can improve performance by using kernel bypass, however, that assumes that you are able to craft a faster network stack that the entire linux kernel comunity. Which could be true if you are willing to ignore edge cases or features you are sure you will never use. Though I imagine it is a very involved processes for perhaps a few percent gain, just so you are warned.

Comment: In my evaluation, in order to get a high tput of 20Gbps+ at this stage, CPU computing power, skb alloc/free, cache, and heavy linux networking stack have become bottlenecks.   I followed XDP because I saw that it supports zero copy, no skb alloc/free, and can bypass the kernel networking stack.  From your description, I understand that there seem to be various obstacles and limitations in using XDP at present. My simplest thought at the moment is to just use XDP for an app's UDP packets to increase the RX speed, seems like this would be relatively easier, right?

Comment: You are correct as to the advantages of AF_XDP(zero copy and no skb alloc). But AF_XDP is not a drop in replacement for a TCP socket. You will get L2 packets/frames in the order the NIC gets them, no reodering, no defragmentation of IP packets, no error checks and correct(it depends on what the hardware does before it passes the data, some NICs do more than others). But I think you can get away with using UDP packets, since they are very easy without much guarantees. But I have to ask, which phone has a 20Gbps+ throughput? :)

Comment: There is really no such phone at this stage, but I have to look to the future. I am trying my best to achieve this goal on my emulator. I have to think about some effective ways to get a higher tput. It's a bit of a headache to be honest.